# Cocoa/Objective-C Plugins Collisions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

My application has a plugin system that allows my users to write their own plugins that get loaded at runtime. Usually this is fine but in some cases two plugins use the same libraries that will cause a collision between those two.

Example:

**Plugin A** wants to use *TouchJSON* for working with JSON and thus the creator adds the TouchJSON code to the plugin source and it gets compiled and linked into the plugin binary. Later **Plugin B** also wants to use that same library and does exactly the same. Now when my app loads these two different plugins it detects this and spits out an warning like this:

> Class CJSONScanner is implemented in
>   both [path_to_plugin_a] and
>   [path_to_plugin_b]. One of the two
>   will be used. Which one is undefined.

Since my app just loads plugins and makes sure they conform to a certain protocol I have no control over which plugins are loaded and if two or more use the same library.

As long as both plugins use the exact same version of the library this will probably work but as soon as the API changes in one plugin a bunch of problems will arise.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle loading system provides no mean to pacifically resolve name conflicts. In fact, we're told to [ensure ourselves that the problem doesn't happen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/NameConflicts.html), rather than what to do if it happens. (Obviously, in your case, that's not possible).

You could [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with this issue.

If this is absolutely critical to your application, you may want to have bundles live in separate processes and use some kind of IPC, possibly `NSDistantObject`, to pass the data from your program to the plugin hosts. However, I'm fairly sure this is a bag of hurt, so if you don't have very clearly-defined interfaces that allow for distribution into different processes, it might be quite an undertaking.

Comment: Just like I thought. I'm just wondering if nobody is running into this issue when there are quite a few Mac apps that allow plugins (Coda, TextMate, Xcode etc)

Comment: @zneak you mean file a bug report with TouchJSON for not providing a framework?

Answer (score 2):

In a single-process model, the only way to deal with this is to ensure that the shared code (more precisely, the shared Objective-C classes) is loaded once. There are two ways to do this:

- Put the shared code in a framework.
- Put the shared code in a loadable bundle, and load the bundle when the plug-in is loaded if the relevant classes aren’t already available (check using `NSClassFromString()`). The client code would also have to use `NSClassFromString()` rather than referring to classes directly.

Of course, if you aren’t in control of the plug-ins you can’t enforce either of these schemes. The best you can do is provide appropriate guidelines and possibly infrastructure; for instance, in the second case the loading could be handled by the application, perhaps by specifying a class to check for and the name of an embedded bundle to load if it isn’t available in the plug-in’s *Info.plist*.